# How do I create a query which takes certain time to execute?

Tags: postgresql

I have configured `statement_timeout=1000` in Postgres DB

I am accessing a DB table using a JDBC driver from a java application. JDBC driver will throw an exception if the statement times out. I have a logic that will get executed if the exception is thrown.

Now I want to test this functionality, is there a way to make a query not return the result within `1000` millsecs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @McNets suggests in his comment, this is really easy using the `pg_sleep()` function:

```
select pg_sleep(2);
```

will return after 2 seconds. And the resulting dataset will contain one row and one column too, so your test application can easily handle it (if it gets through the timeout).